# MySQL profiler cuts queries more that 300 characters length

Tags: mysql, profiler

MySQL profiler cuts queries more that 300 characters length when i get the list of queries by

```
 SHOW PROFILES
```

And i see queries like this:

```
 SELECT media_videos.`id` AS `media_videos.id`, media_videos.`user_id` AS `media_videos.user_id`, media_videos.`description` AS `media_videos.description`, media_videos.`likes` AS `media_videos.likes`, media_videos.`video` AS `media_videos.video`, media_videos.`resource` AS `media_videos.resource`,
```

(It's an automatically generated query so it can be really long)

So it shows ALL queries but big ones are cut to 300 chars and i can't see them to the end.

How can i fix that using MySQL tools only (not to profile queries in my app manually)? May be some directives in my.cnf ??

Thank you!

Comment: You will probably have to go direct to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING table to get the full text of the longer queries. Each query has a QUERY_ID so you can walk the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe not the answer you wanted, but the answer nonetheless:

SHOW PROFILE is implemented in sql/sql_profile.cc

Code fragments below:

```
#define MAX_QUERY_LENGTH 300U
```

used in

```
void QUERY_PROFILE::set_query_source(char *query_source_arg,
                                     uint query_length_arg)
{
  /* Truncate to avoid DoS attacks. */
  uint length= min(MAX_QUERY_LENGTH, query_length_arg);
  ...
```

So, short of recompiling the server with a bigger value, SHOW PROFILE will truncate the query to 300 characters, no matter what.